# Webview is not displaying the data until user clear the app data

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I am displaying the HTML page which consist of some buttons..when user clicks on any button java script alert is going to show..

I am finishing my screen in onPause(). Once the user user press button in html file ,then javascript alert is showing and user press home button ,then application is going to pause and i am finishing the screen.then system is displaying the leaked window error message in the logcat.

The interesting is when the user open the same html ,the webview is not displaying the data,it is displaying the error message as "webview: OnSizeChanged: Enter" ..

Once user clear the app data ,then it is displaying the data.

Here is the properties i set to webview ,still it is not working.

```
mDecryptDataWv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    mDecryptDataWv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    mDecryptDataWv.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    mDecryptDataWv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    mDecryptDataWv.clearHistory();
    mDecryptDataWv.clearFormData();
    mDecryptDataWv.clearCache(true);
```

Can any one help me on resolving this issue..

Answer (score 0):

This part sounds concerning:

> then application is going to pause and i am finishing the screen.then
>   system is displaying the leaked window error message in the logcat.

If the user hits the home button, you shouldn't need to do anything in the onPause method to "finish the screen".

What exactly are you doing during onPause?

Comment: My application requirement is once the activity goes to onPause(),user should exit from the application. so i am calling the finish() in onPause() to come out of the activity.i am stoping the asyntask's which are running and making the objects as null for the memory issues...

Comment: You should only need to call finish() - Setting the objects to null, unless are singletons, shouldn't really be necessary, the garbage collector will clean up regardless. Could you create an example project on github or something similar that replicates the issues?